# Adding digits of phone numbers together, returning the largest

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to break down each phone number (string), remove the "-", then add each digit of the number together, returning the largest.  I'm able to remove "-" but I'm not able to take the new array and add each digit returning the largest....

```
var phoneNumbers = ['222-111-2234', '998-887-2222', '991-111-1111']; 

for (var i=0;i<phoneNumbers.length;i++) { 
    var numberString = phoneNumbers[i].replace(/-/g,''); 
    var number = parseInt(numberString,10); 
    numbers[i] = number; 
} 
var largestNumber = numbers[0]; 
    for (var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) { 
    if (numbers[i] > largestNumber) { 
    largestNumber = numbers[i]; 
} 
} 
return largestNumber;
```

Comment: Please search for duplicates, of which several exist.

Comment: parseInt doesn't add the digits together

Comment: must be a common tutorial somewhere. Should find lots of solutions on this site for exact same problem

Comment: All you had to do was look at ***Related Links*** on right side of this page